# Dictionary not selecting correct key

Tags: python

I have a strange problem with one of my dictionaries.

Below is a method that will execute another method based on the time frame it receives. The time frames are m1, m5, m15, m30, H1, H4, D1, W1, M1.

Basically from 1 minute to 1 month.

```
def get_trading_range(self, init_date, time_frame):
    """
    """
    key = time_frame[:1]
    tr_dict = {
        'D' : self._daily_range(init_date),
        'W' : self._weekly_range(init_date),
        'M' : self._monthly_range(init_date),
        'H' : self._hourly_range(init_date, time_frame),
        'm' : self._minutely_range(init_date, time_frame)
    }
    return tr_dict[key]
```

The method is called with the following

```
DateRange().get_trading_range(datetime(some_date), 'D1')
```

It seems to be selecting the 'm' method. I tried removing the 'm' key and value, then when executed again it selects the 'H' method. Only when I remove both the 'm' & 'H' keys and values will the 'D' method be executed.

Is this some strange bug?

This is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "engine.py", line 25, in _historical
    HistoricalCollector().historical_prices(hist_queue, live_queue, event)
  File "/home/nonroot/fxcmminer_1.1/fxcm/historical.py", line 90, in historical_prices
    self._historical_iter(hist_queue, live_queue, fxoffer)
  File "/home/nonroot/fxcmminer_1.1/fxcm/historical.py", line 73, in _historical_iter
    self._collect_data(fxc, offer, time_frame, init_date)
  File "/home/nonroot/fxcmminer_1.1/fxcm/historical.py", line 28, in _collect_data
    dtx = DateRange().get_trading_range(init_date, time_frame)
  File "/home/nonroot/fxcmminer_1.1/fxcm/tradinghours.py", line 84, in get_trading_range
    'm' : self._minutely_range(init_date, time_frame),
  File "/home/nonroot/fxcmminer_1.1/fxcm/tradinghours.py", line 103, in _minutely_range
    freq = self._data_frequency(time_frame)[0]
  File "/home/nonroot/fxcmminer_1.1/fxcm/tradinghours.py", line 23, in _data_frequency
    return freq_keys[time_frame]
KeyError: 'D1'
```

Also tried with `key = time_frame[0]`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "engine.py", line 25, in _historical
    HistoricalCollector().historical_prices(hist_queue, live_queue, event)
  File "/home/nonroot/fxcmminer_1.1/fxcm/historical.py", line 90, in historical_prices
    self._historical_iter(hist_queue, live_queue, fxoffer)
  File "/home/nonroot/fxcmminer_1.1/fxcm/historical.py", line 73, in _historical_iter
    self._collect_data(fxc, offer, time_frame, init_date)
  File "/home/nonroot/fxcmminer_1.1/fxcm/historical.py", line 28, in _collect_data
    dtx = DateRange().get_trading_range(init_date, str(time_frame))
  File "/home/nonroot/fxcmminer_1.1/fxcm/tradinghours.py", line 84, in get_trading_range
    'm' : self._minutely_range(init_date, time_frame),
  File "/home/nonroot/fxcmminer_1.1/fxcm/tradinghours.py", line 103, in _minutely_range
    freq = self._data_frequency(time_frame)[0]
  File "/home/nonroot/fxcmminer_1.1/fxcm/tradinghours.py", line 23, in _data_frequency
    return freq_keys[time_frame]
KeyError: 'D1'
```

Comment: Try `key = time_frame[0]`?

Comment: You're giving as key D1 where only the key D exists. Don't see a problem with the exception raised, as D1 certainly does not exist.

Comment: After reading your edit, I think you are misinterpreting the source of the error. Is there any other place the dict is being used with these keys?

Comment: @Shiva 100% certain this is the only place. Its the first method in the  `DateRange()` class that starts everything off. Also the key hits correclty when I remove 'm' and 'H'

Comment: The problem is not in the posted method, but in your `_hourly_range()` and `_minutely_range()` methods to which you are sending your `time_frame` and they are trying to find it in their `freq_keys` dictionary (because it doesn't exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that those method get called when `tr_dict` is created, not when you access it, and this is why your `_minutely_range` is getting called with `time_frame = "D1"`.

Try something like:

```
tr_dict = {
    'D' : lambda: self._daily_range(init_date),
    'W' : lambda: self._weekly_range(init_date),
    'M' : lambda: self._monthly_range(init_date),
    'H' : lambda: self._hourly_range(init_date, time_frame),
    'm' : lambda: self._minutely_range(init_date, time_frame)
}
return tr_dict[key]()
```

This way, the methods will be called only if necessary.

Comment: You are correct.. I need to read the docs on `lambda` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the function isn't returning 'm' or 'H', but is in the process of evaluating them when it hits the traceback. Could it be `key` you want to pass into their functions instead of `time_frame`?